# Generalized Euler substitution

Tags: integration, substitution

I've came across Euler substitutions today, then I saw the generalized substitution which can work on any case of the 3 cases using complex numbers but I didn't find any example on it, so can you please provide examples on this substitution, and extend it to the logarithmic rational functions like in the blockquote below:

> Generalizations
> The substitutions of Euler can be generalized by allowing the use of imaginary numbers. For example, in the integral $\int \frac{d x}{\sqrt{-x^{2}+c}}$, the substitution $\sqrt{-x^{2}+c}=\pm i x+t$ can be used. Extensions to the complex numbers allows us to use every type of Euler substitution regardless of the coefficients on the quadratic.
> The substitutions of Euler can be generalized to a larger class of functions. Consider integrals of the form
> $$
> \int R_{1}\left(x, \sqrt{a x^{2}+b x+c}\right) \log \left(R_{2}\left(x, \sqrt{a x^{2}+b x+c}\right)\right) d x,
> $$
> where $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$ are rational functions of $x$ and $\sqrt{a x^{2}+b x+c}$. This integral can be transformed by the substitution $\sqrt{a x^{2}+b x+c}=\sqrt{a}+x t$ into another integral
> $$
> \int \tilde{R}_{1}(t) \log \left(\tilde{R}_{2}(t)\right) d t
> $$
> where $\tilde{R}_{1}(t)$ and $\tilde{R}_{2}(t)$ are now simply rational functions of $t$. In principle, factorization and partial fraction decomposition can be employed to break the integral down into simple terms, which can be integrated analytically through use of the dilogarithm function. ${ }^{[2]}$